# Interrupting build process on failure

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which performs few steps of build process but even though error occurs during certain step it still continues building. Is it expected behaviour? Or maybe I am doing something incorrectly?

```
all:
    cd projects/project1/; $(MAKE); cd ../..
    cd projects/project2/; $(MAKE); cd ../..
    cd projects/project3/; $(MAKE); cd ../..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the return code of a recipe line stems from the last executed command in that recipe line - in your case this is `cd ../..` which will not fail even though the immediately preceding recursive makefile may have failed. So for the main makefile this line returns ok and it does not stop. The good news: as every recipe line is executed in a shell (`sh` ! not `bash` unless you tell make explicitly) this means that the terminal `cd ../..` is completely dispensable as the shell executing it is closed immediately afterwards. Drop it and your makefile should behave as you want.

BTW you should write `cd subdir && $(MAKE)` or `$(MAKE) -C subdir` so that you catch non-existent directories too.

You may consider a non-recursive way of writing your makefile, tho. Google for "Recursive make considered harmful" and decide if the described problems ring a bell...